# Human versus robot/AI politicians

Tags: politics, law, robots

If the government were run by robots instead of politicians, and these robots had to reach out to the masses for every single decision they made, wouldn't the world be a better place because robots would be resistant to life threats by bullying parties to pass bad laws and engage in unwanted wars etc.?

The only downside is that keeping up with everything by citizens could take up a lot of their time, and they could engage in forums related to political issues and then vote a lot... But then what would be more important than politics and law in a "correct world"?

Comment: If the robots have to reach out to the masses for every decision, how is this different from direct democracy?  I.e. why do you need robots?

Comment: Because a politician can be threatened to pass a law that is unethical by pressure groups. A robot that acts in a purely Democratic fashion would not have to put up with these pressures and corrupt money offers which a robot would have no need for.

Comment: But why do you need politicians?  It's a direct democracy.  Politicians can't pass laws in direct democracies.  What do the robots do?  It seems that you are implying that they replace the politicians, but politicians are unnecessary for the system that you describe.  So why replace them?

Comment: I am not very good at law and politics, but I know that in many countries politicians are elected with expectations in mind, and then the politicians do what they want with laws and governing without consulting the people our going back on their words. Is this not so?

Comment: Politicians are elected with campaign promises in mind. Then these promises run into a real world that is constantly changing. Somebody runs on the basis of lowering taxes and raising welfare, then there is a recession. Somebody else runs on the basis of changing abortion and gun laws. He doesn't get an outright majority, but there is someone else who would offer to help with *one* of the planks of the platform in exchange for the other. Politics is the art of forging compromise solutions.

Comment: Are you saying politicians don't know how the crowd will react to conflicting promises and cannot predict economical phase shifts?

Comment: So you say we should only accept clairvoyant politicians?

Comment: Even a clairvoyant politician may have to make a decision that is unfair to society if they fear their own life is at stake and don't see a way out.

Comment: You mean [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factions_in_Revelation_Space#Demarchists)?

Comment: @JDlugosz, the demarchyst approach in the Wikipedia article is interesting, but I don't understand how the "good" in quotation marks on the Wikipedia link would be assessed. Maybe you can explain.

Comment: You should read the *Revalation Space* stories. I don't recall how much detail it goes into (I've not read *the Prefect* yet but it souds like he explores it in more detail here.)

Comment: You might also check the story mentioned at the end by Joan Vinge.

Comment: Two fictions with countries that were ran by computers, for inspiration: *Neon Genesis Evangelion* and *The Matrix* (before the Matrix was created, there was a robot county called Zero One).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfect political AI would run a government perfectly.  The problem is that perfect is really hard to define, and the stakes are quite high.

One approach might be a robot that follows rules. For example, it may be told to enforce the opinion of the majority.  However, this is not as ideal as it may seem.  The knowledge with which to make good decisions is not universal.  The public is NOT educated enough to decide a location for a nuclear powerplant.  The public is not educated enough to decide whether we should go to war.  There isn't enough time in the day to be educated enough on all issues, this is why there is division of labor.  Plus, in the case of war, some of the essential information may be classified, and not safe to dissiminate.

In general, rule based systems are hard to put in place well because you must ceede power to the rules.  You lose the ultimate power the instant you engage the rules.  If you made a mistake, well, rules are rules.  You can add rules to change the rules but that only defers the problem.  There is an infinite regression to deal with there.

On the other extreme, we can give the power to the AI to make decisions.  However, how do we know those decisions will be in our interest before we enact the AI?  There is more than one movie about a AI bound by the wrong rules.  Some of them have even refused to open the pod bay doors.  This ability to decide also opens the door for corruption.  It will be in a slightly different form, rargetting an AId decisions rather than a human 's, but the effect would be the same

So what you want is a balance.  The AI needs to have commitments to some rules, but the freedom to avoid catestrophic misinterpretations.  You have to decide which things you want you AI to hold to while it is in office.  You also have to get some agrements between all of the citizens.  Everyone will have to have some say in what the AI will hold to.

Which is starting to sound a lot like campaign promises , don't you think?

---

Edit: from the comments, I mentioned Isaac Asimov's [Three Laws of Robotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics).  70 years after he wrote them, they're still considered some of the best rules ever written for a robot to follow when working with humans.  For those who are not familiar with them:

1. A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.
2. A robot must obey the orders given it by human beings except where such orders would conflict with the First Law.
3. A robot must protect its own existence as long as such protection does not conflict with the First or Second Laws

Asimov then spent an entire career writing books about the loopholes in these laws, and how each one could play out.  This just goes to show how nuanced such a program would have to be.

Comment: Complicated picture, but real enough. However, I think campaign promises should be coupled with education. I think that would make things better. Can you please comment on this observation?

Comment: Anyways, your explanation is outstanding. But does that mean there is no better system for us than the one we have today, because knowledge acquisition is time consuming, and once all people have the new knowledge, we're on done way back to where we started with?

Comment: And some knowledge is classified, which runs counter to the open source principle to which forums such as these confirm to (unless someone is posting lots of course). :-)

Comment: @JackMaddington I don't think it means there is no better system, just that it's remarkably hard to find a better system with large sweeping changes.  The system we have is as it is because it is balanced between a lot of conflicting goals.  If you try to rewrite the system, it still has to strike a balance between those same goals.  Now what would be interesting is trying to make a process to replace politicians with AIs slowly.  The issue with the original plan is you need to get the answer *right* on the first try, when making the AI.  If the process can be slow and subtle enough to...

Comment: ... give the voting citizens time to feel out how this change affects them, it would give them time to correct any initial mistakes.  Start small, and let it grow =)

Comment: Which legs to the question, has anyone developed a computer simulation of such a system and where can I find it? Sure, if people can try out the simulation and play around with out they may be able to tell which is right for them. People could vote for rules to make it into the AI, although as you say, people may not be knowledgeable enough to make the "right" decisions.

Comment: I'm certain each political party has several computer simulations to help them with such things, and I know I've seen the in games.  Think tanks use them all the time. However, my favorite incubator for such ideas is Isaac Asimov's series of books about the Three Laws of Robotics.  They were such good laws that they still stand tall 70 years later.  I haven't heard of any rules that have been found to be "better."  And yet, Asimov made a living off writing books about all the ways the Three Laws could fail.  Each book explored a different loophole than the last.

Comment: The fact that a set of 3 laws from 70 years ago still ring true suggest strongly that the problem is not a robotic or a computer one, but rather a human one.  Its very easy to write a computer program to solve your problems if you can write your problems down in the language of specification writing.  Historically speaking, that task has been so difficult that many believe such a specification to be impossible to write.

Comment: Interesting. Could you list what these the laws are in your answer

Comment: Sure, they've been added.   Also, a Google search for "Three Law of Robotics" will bring up scores of content on the topic.  They're really famous.

Comment: @CortAmmon The only thing that comes to mind that might trump the Three Laws is to explicitly include the Zeroth law: "A robot may not harm humanity, or, by inaction, allow humanity to come to harm". Of course that one had some loopholes as well, as I recall.

Comment: @JoelHarmon There are many issues that Asimov covered in his career.  For example, what defines a "human?"  Its a harder definition than one might think.  He also explored several ways a robot could kill a human, such as what would happen if the robot was unaware it was killing them (those who investigated assumed it was impossible for a robot to kill, so the actual killer went unquestioned).  The issues with the laws were myriad, and yet they are held in high esteem because we haven't been able to do much better.

Comment: @CortAmmon I think we're in violent agreement here. You commented " I haven't heard of any rules that have been found to be "better." ". I mostly agree with that, as long as you include the Zeroth Law that he introduced in his Foundation and Earth novel. I simply feel any description of the laws is incomplete without this fourth.

Comment: @JoelHarmon My point is more that I believe Asimov showed the laws were incomplete, even with the Zeroth's law.  It took something more, something beyond a set of laws to make his AIs compatible with us.  In fact, the thing I find most interesting about the Zeroth law is that the moment it becomes a law, it fails to serve its purpose (In fact, around that time, Alfred Tarksi was formulating his non-definiability theorem which captures these issues in cold mathematical formulations)

Comment: "A perfect political AI would run a government perfectly." IMO, things are far more subtle than that. If a perfect political AI was to run a government perfectly, then by necessity the power would be drawn away from people (this AI could allow people to make some decisions, but nevertheless it would retain the last word). Hence, people couldn't rule their own state. It is very possible that people would actually like to rule their own state and be responsible for it, even if they couldn't do it perfectly.

Comment: Under this AI, they would be like "big children" - theoretically adult, nevertheless not grown up since this AI would act like a parent for them. We're touching here the problem of effectiveness vs freedom and responsibility. Such a perfect AI would maximize effectiveness, however at the cost of freedom.

Comment: @gaazkam "A perfect political AI would run a government perfectly" is simply a tautology to start the exploration into what a "perfect political AI" could plausibly mean.  The interesting quest is for what "perfect" means to you.  It sounds like you have opinions on that already.  There's a vast landscape of solutions to the issues you bring up, but it's hard to explore if you assume the question is already solved or is already unsolvable before we start.  That's why I start with a statement to encourage the assumption it is solvable, but then speak to the drawbacks from that point on.

Comment: Freedom is actually an interesting topic to explore.  It seems simple until you actually start digging into what it means.  I know plenty of people who are in the process of actively destroying their freedoms as fast as they possibly can, but believe they are maximizing their freedom.  It's a tricky topic.  It gets even more tricky when you start bringing religion into the mix, because many religions include constructs which truly make us all "big children," subject to the whims of the deity.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the term *robot* is used for machines with some sort of manipulators. What you are looking for would be an *AI* which may or may not be running on a [robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot); it could be running on a virtual machine in a [cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) as well. But language use may be shifting in this regard.

Your plan that the machine would listen to popular opinion but not to "unethical" pressure is a contradiction. Most of the pressure groups also represent a slice of popular opinion, which may be very vocal even if they do not have a majority. If the machine can make ethical decisions about which pressure to resist and which pressure to accept as popular opinion, why wouldn't it be complex enough to worry about its own future?

Also, a society that is administrated *without* human compassion could be even worse than a society that is administrated *with* human passion.

Comment: I like your answer. Actually, I feel you have understood my question though, because many pressure groups which represent a large slice of society actually do lack in human compassion (think of assessing debilitating psychiatric drugs, unsuccessful cancer treatments, and large scale chemically toxic fertilizers and genetic modifications to foods, for instance). So, an AI agent would have to take the health and biological functioning of its people as Ann ethical principle to resist pressure groups.

Comment: But the pressure groups' propagandas and dissemination of false information prevention would have to be taken into account here. What is your take on this? What do you suggest must I do to improve my worldbuilding exercise while retaining the spirit of my original question?

Comment: You could have a fictional world where well-meaning people try to institute AI government, perhaps after a scandal. Make sure that *some* of the opponents of this scheme do so for good reasons. And have a few problems on the way. Perhaps the literal application of the law leads to a great injustice in a specific case. People call for the AI ruler to issue a pardon. The AI resists this pressure and the sentence stands. There is a disaster with GM food. People call for a ban on GM. The AI ruler resists this pressure and preserves the rights of GM companies.

Comment: Then again, if the AI ruler were also a machine algorithm, so that it could resist life threats, how could it do these things, how could it being so "humanely smart" be plausible or even technically feasible from a computer science standpoint?

Comment: @JackMaddington, I don't think physical threats are the problem here. The most common assassins are lone madmen without a coherent agenda. Underhanded tactics come into play when corporations fund candidates for benefits, or fund both sides and then threaten to withdraw the money. An AI that is smart enough to rule a nation might be smart enough to want to stay in power, too, and make compromises.

Comment: Hi, ok, perhaps "underhand tactics" is a better word for what I meant, but I still think there can be a certain degree of bullying involved. What if the AI ruler were made up of a distributed computing system so that it would be harder to wipe it out by any individual party?

Answer (score 1):

In Asimov’s story, the AI (named Multivac as with a number of stories that feature a computer) is so smart that it cannot be disobeyed, even thougn its global planning is only advisory and not law. If it recomended planting X acres of wheat, and you decided to disobey, well, it *knew* you would not all along, and secretly manipulated you to choosing what it really intended and/or included your predicted planting in its overall plans.

In another story, a Positronic robot passing as human ran for president, so it could do the most good for humanity.

In general, we have the problem that politicians are good at getting power, not necessarily good at anything else like rational problem solving. Having machines run things would be different in that they would be *built for that purpose* and very skilled in the necessary areas.

That would include compassion and selflessness, so it would not have the pressures you noted but neither would have the flaws noted by other answers. But really, it all depends on how the machine was made. In that sense the question has no definitive answer. I can answer as what could be optimal, but the story lies in how it really turned out.

Comment: Interesting answer. What I do not understand is how compassion can be built in. Often being compassionate towards one cause could mean being uncompassionate about something else. Also, it seems to me like language, which is what a robot would likely use as logic, would influence what was compassionate and what was not.

Comment: People like the Multivac in Asimov's story exist in real life in my opinion. But they are the smart people nobody knows who actually are able to influence or rule elected politicians, lawyers, and other people in positions of power.

Comment: How would a machine know how someone felt? If such person did not report back the machine might never know. But without doing something to that person they might not know either, and that something could be somewhat uncompassionate? How could the machine possibly know every action',s outcome if programmed by ignorant people?

Comment: Know how someone feels: how does anyone?  Multivac knowing enough to predict behavior: not explained. *today* can suppose global detailed information gathering like in the TV show *Person of Interest*.

Comment: I've never seen the show "Person of Interest", must be interesting. Do you have a YouTube link?